# Xbox one X - surround with stereo headphones is possible

Tags: xbox-one, audio-hardware

I have an xbox one x connected to my TV and the amplifier

Since I would like to play without disturbing other people, I would like to know if is possible to get a surround effect with stereo headphones, for surround effect I mean something like a 5.1 setup with sound moving from the back to the front.

I read some articles and saw some videos about that and is not really clear to me if virtual surround headphones are different from simple stereo headphones since I guess the equalizer would be the xbox ( I  guess )

EDIT:

I edit my question because I'm pretty confuse about surround / headphone and console :-)

What I would like to do is to have surround sound inside headphone while playing on xbox one X ( if is possible )

Do i need a gaming headphone if I want to use it with xbox one x or any headphone could work?

Does virtual surround headphone use some sort of surround effect to simulate surround and is not necessary on xbox because the console also does it?

Can the correct headphone simulate a 5.1 / 7.1 and the sound of an object moving from back to front?

I remove the video since seems not to be relevant.

Comment: If the question is "Is it possible to simulate surround sound with stereo headphones?" I don't think this is on topic, maybe Super User?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, but all Xbox Ones support 7.1 surround sound.  Using the headphone jack on the controller, I can certainly tell you that the surround sound experience using my headphones is very good.

Comment: The video in your question has nothing to do with what you are asking. Essentially you're asking how to get surround sound from your xbox to headphones, not the different between headphone sets.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: I will retract my downvote as this is now a better worded question

Comment: From what I understand you need surround sound capable headphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a gaming question, but:

> What I would like to do is to have surround sound inside headphone while playing on xbox one X ( if is possible )

Xbox One supports surround sound if you have the appropriate audio devices for it. Stereo headphones will not have surround sound.

> Do i need a gaming headphone if I want to use it with xbox one x or any headphone could work?

Any headphones will work with your Xbox One. Whatever materials were included with the headphones (manual, the box they came in, etc.) will indicate if they are stereo or surround sound.

> Does virtual surround headphone use some sort of surround effect to simulate surround and is not necessary on xbox because the console also does it?

This is extremely dependent on what game you're playing. Surround sound can be simulated in stereo, but this isn't the same as having multiple speakers. Not all games will support proper surround sound, nor will all games simulate it for stereo output.

> Can the correct headphone simulate a 5.1 / 7.1 and the sound of an object moving from back to front?

This is what depends on what game you're playing. Directional audio can be simulated in stereo, but this is done by the game, not your headphones.

Answer (score 1):

Surround sound headphones will only work if your headphones support it.

If your headphones only has two speakers, there's no physical way for it to simulate "forward" and "backwards" on it.  You just physically cannot do it.

Comment: It is very much possible to [simulate direction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_surround) with only two speakers using psychoacoustics.